# ReactNavigation: How to disable all header/nav and view only screen in navigator?

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I have a recursive react navigator and I want to see a particular screen in "full screen" mode, that is without all navigators tabs.

My Navigator is:

```
createSwitchNavigator({
...
App: createDrawerNavigator({
  Main: createBottomTabNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
      screen: createStackNavigator({
        Dashboard: createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
          DashboardDevice: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
              Device: dashboardDeviceScreen,
              DeviceDetail: dashboardDeviceDetailScreen,
            }, deviceStackOptions),
            navigationOptions: { title: 'DISPOSITIVI' },
          },
        }, dashboardTopOptions),
      }, dashboardStackOptions),
      navigationOptions: dashboardOptions,
    },
    ...
  }, mainBottomTabOptions),
}, drawerOptions),
```

When I navigate to **DeviceDetail** I would not like to see all navigators tab but only the screen with a backButton.

Thanks

Comment: put your DeviceDetail under Stack Navigator instead of Tab Navigator

Comment: if I move DeviceDetail under Stack Navigator, I don't preserve a Navigation properties (example params in Stack Device, backButton etc).